# How to call Function from an C# dll in Java?

Tags: java, c#, dll, java-native-interface, sap-dotnet-connector

i have a SAP-DLL to enable communication between a Programming interface and the SAP Programm.

I have following example Code for c# in combination with the dll-File:

```
var loggerService = LoggerService.GetLoggerService("FileLogger");
var itasProxy = SapProxyFactory.CreateSapProxy(SapSystem.Example, loggerService, "Example_User", StringExtension.CreateSecureString("Example_Password")); 
var funcResult = sapProxy.SearchSapAddress(clientNo);

if (funcResult.Successfull)
{
    funcResult.ReturnValue = withFormatting
        ? AddressFormatter.SplitStreetHouseNo(funcResult.ReturnValue)
        : funcResult.ReturnValue;
}
```

Now i want the same functionality to be transferred to java. I have absolutely no clue how to do that. I tried the following with Loggerservice as a starter, but it doesn't work:

```
public class SAPConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connectSAP();
    }
    public void connectSAP()
    {
        System.load("C://Temp//SapConnector.dll");
        Object loggerService = getLoggerService("FileLogger");
    }
    public native Object getLoggerService(String lcLogger);
}
```

i just need some kind of information how to call the Functions from the dll or an example how to transfer the C# Code to working Code in Java.

Greetings,

Kevin

Comment: @john: no it isn't the thread you posted is based on an entirely different dll-Problem

Comment: Fine, I'll delete my duplicate suggestions. You are, however, looking for a way to call C# code from Java, are you not? If that is not the case, you should re-word your question.

Comment: I can´t see what those two snippets have in common. From my opinion they are completely different. Anyway when you write "doesn´t work", what does that mean? Show exactlx what you´ve tried and what problems you got on doing so. This includes your current cide and every error/exception/unexpected behaviour/unexpected results you get.

Comment: yes, i am, but  you have to read my text. It is a special case, i already tried several things that i read at stackoverflow, nothing work, because i can't get the right syntax for the native support. My dll uses it's own classes and data types and i have no idea how to get java to recognize these functions and data types, i just need one example from my code i posted so that i can find a solution

Comment: @HimBromBeere with the code i have now i get the error UnsatisfiedClassLink on the line 10 in my java code.... and like i said, the first snippet is the working c# Code in combination with the dll, now i need that same code with same functionality to be working in java :)

Comment: JNI depends on a shared library (DLL) exporting public static functions (dumpbin /exports). C++/CLI is the typical .NET language to create such a DLL, though you can massage an existing .NET assembly to export any public static function. In any case, since you probably don't have public static functions that are exactly what the JNI linkage created by javah requires, you'll have to write bridging code and so it might as well be in C++/CLI. Or, just something like JNBridge.

Answer (score 3):

[DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) is Microsoft format. Java is cross-platform, thus can't acknowledge anything operating-system specific, such as DLL.

One way around that is to use [JNI (Java Native Interface)](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/stepbystep/index.html), but that's usually not a good solution, as it makes your program platform-dependent.

Instead, I would look for a JAR from SAP, that provides a similar interface.
Maybe something along [SAP JCO](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SI/Java+Connectivity).

You can see some [actual code examples using JCO here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/25/sap-jco-server-example/), and some [technical information on step-by-step download and configure here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/02/11/step-by-step-to-download-and-configure-jco-to-your-laptop/).

Comment: thanks for the comment, i already searched for it, but for now i have to get this working... like you saw, i tried JNI, but i think i made a mistake or forgot something, it's the first time i use it ...another solution i had in mind is make the code with vbs and call the vbs script from java, but that's not a good solution as well...

Comment: Although Java is plattform-independent - as .NET also (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656721/is-net-platform-independent) - this doesn´t mean every java-code can be run on any OS. There exist many such programs that only run on windows-machines. Having said this JNI is exactly what OP needs and calling a .NET-assembly from JAVA is absolutely okay.

Comment: @HimBromBeere is my syntax ok? or did i miss something to get this working?

Comment: Yeah, well, I agree it is very much dependent on your business scenario. I would be very surprised if SAP don't supply the same thing in a JAR, though. They are more Java-Oriented than many other companies. 
@KevinBarz if you do go with JNI, maybe the Tutorial in the link can help you. Did you follow the same steps?

Comment: @YoavGur i already tried several things, that's why i was looking for an answer, but i will try again with your tutorial

Comment: in step 5 of your link is mentioned that you need to compile the .c and .h file into an DLL, but i already have an DLL, what do i miss?

Comment: .c- and .h-files don´t even exist on .NET, those are source- and header-files for C. Anyway you should be able to use the DLL you allready have, you don´t need those source-files.

Comment: @HimBromBeere:Can you then give me an example of how to implement a method from the DLL (from the xample i posted above) in java?

Comment: I can't see how this would work without the dedicated jni header file. To load a DLL in C, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034728/load-dll-library

Comment: Added link to explanation about SAP JCO API.